# trouble with PHP's password_verify

Tags: php, authentication, hash, passwords

So, I'me coding a simple login system with php.

here's the registration code:

```
  if ($hash == $hash2) {

            $pass = password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        } else {

          $message = "As password não são iguais.\\nTenta de novo.";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '../registo.php';</script>";
    echo "</script>";

        }

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (hash) VALUES ('$pass')";
```

the form for log in:

```
<form class="form" id="formLogin" style="color:#ffffff" action="stuff/login.php" method="post">

    password:
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="" style="background-color: #ffffff; color:#111111;" ><br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="btnLogin" style="padding-top: 5%; padding-bottom: 5%; color:#ffffff" class="btn btn-default outline center-block">Login</button>
</form>
```

My login.php (to simplify I'm using a fixed id of the database in the query and only a password field)

```
require_once("db.php");
require("password.php");

if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {

    $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    $id = 1;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id ='$id'";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $h = $row['hash'];

    if($numRows == 1) {
        if(password_verify($pass, $h)) {
            header("Location: ../backoffice.php");
        } else {
            $message = $pass . "   " . $h;
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            echo "</script>";

        }
    } else {
        $message = "a palavra-passe e/ou nome de utilizador est\343o errados.\\nTenta de novo.";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');";
            echo "window.location = '../index.php';";
        echo "</script>";
    }
};
```

When I echo the $message in the else part of the password_verify's if, to display both the input password and the database hash, they seem ok - the right string outcome from the log in form, and the correct hash stored in the database. 
But yet, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);` Why?

Comment: @MarkBaker was wondering the same thing, maybe try filter_input() instead?

Comment: Doesn't need anything changing in password at all, any form of filtering or manipulation is actually reducing the entropy of the password

Comment: What is not working? the header to redirect? If that is what is not working make sure you don't send anything to the cleint before you reach that line.

Comment: another thing; what is the password column's length? if it's anything less than 60, then your query failed on you silently.

Comment: comments posted; none replied. we ask for clarification but get nothing.

Comment: So, let me answer: - htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']); not really sure either. I'm a noob, I copied some lines from other older previous project of mine that contained that. But it didn't affect the outcome. (thanks for the info, tho ;) )
- what is not working is the password_verify part, which in the case is the redirect. It displays the "error message" (the else)
- i have a value of 255 in the database columns length, I already fell for that in the past.

- i am very sorry for the reply time

Comment: Was the password hash created using the `password_hash()` function?

Comment: Yes, Mark. Just   $pass = password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); and then I insert it in the database. After that I can see the hash both in the database and on the echo I make the else of the password_verify's if.

Comment: @Zimutes - Hopefully you meant it the other way round: `$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`. Can you show us the registration code as well?

Comment: Yes, I meant it the other way round. 
I'll edit the Question to add the registration code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is a problem in your **password_verify** function. Maybe you are trying to match password with it's hash. Check id value and if there any character of the password is being skipped for **htmlspecialchars** function.

Comment: I tested without the htmlspecialchars with the same result.

Comment: [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) is a standard PHP function, and has been for nearly 4 years now; and its whole purpose is to compare a plaintext password with its hash value